# CSS inline-block white space between elements

Tags: html, css

I want to remove or reduce the white-space between elements. This is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/AWMMT/41/):

```css
.Col1 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    margin:0;
}

.Col2 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Col1"><h4>Art/Dance:</h4></div>
<div class="Col2"><p><span id="Art_S">$123</span></p></div>
 <!-- Row 2 -->
<div class="Col1"><h4>Cloth:</h4></div>
<div class="Col2"><p><span id="Cloth_S">$123</span></p></div>
 <!-- Row 3 -->
<div class="Col1"><h4>Education:</h4></div>
<div class="Col2"><p><span id="Education_S">$123</span></p></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
```

Solution 1:  font-size: 0 on Parent

```
.inline-block-list { /* ul or ol with this class */
    font-size: 0;
}

.inline-block-list li {
    font-size: 14px; /* put the font-size back */
}
```

Solution 2:  HTML Comments

```
<ul>
    <li>Item content</li><!--
 --><li>Item content</li><!--
 --><li>Item content</li>
</ul>
```

Solution 3:  Negative Margin

```
.inline-block-list li {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

Solution 4:  Dropping Closing Angle

```
<ul>
    <li>Item content</li
 ><li>Item content</li
 ><li>Item content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Still the white space, please take a look to my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/AWMMT/41/

Comment: I need more explanation on the problem

Comment: theres a gap between each <div>. And I whant to remove or reduce this white space.

Comment: refers to the height space

Comment: Yes, the height.
thank you very much!! I use height:1px; and its work!
thank you again!

Comment: is not advisable to use `height:1px;`. you add: `p,h4{margin:0;padding:0;}`

Comment: is a pleasure to help